# Reloading a page inside of a <div> with $_GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, refresh

The following page loads inside of  on my index.php.  I initially call it using the following link:  Import Mutuals

This part works dandy. The problem I'm having is with the refresh code at the bottom:  var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){\$('#import').show('fast').load('fb_import_statuses.php?i=$i').show('fast');}, 1000);

I want it to initially load with record 1 and then keep refreshing, updating my SQL until it reaches record 255.  If I do this same code outside of a DIV using Meta Refresh it steps through the sequence fine, but using this JavaScript refresh it will sequence like this:

1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc...

How can I get it to sequence as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 etc...

```
require 'batch_include.php';
require 'html_head.php';

if (isset($_GET['i'])){$i = $_GET["i"];} else {$i=0;}

$getcount = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS get_count FROM people", $conn);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getcount)){$get_count = "".$row{'get_count'}."";}

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM people LIMIT ".$i.",1", $conn);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                                    
        $get_uid = addslashes("".$row{'id'}.""); 

    $me_friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT     status_id, message, source, time FROM status WHERE uid="'.$get_uid.'" LIMIT 5'));
    foreach ($me_friends as $fkey=>$me_friends){
        $get_status_id = $me_friends['status_id']; 
        $get_message = addslashes($me_friends['message']); 
        $get_source = $me_friends['source']; 
        $get_timestamp = $me_friends['time']; 

    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO statuses (id, message, source, timestamp, uid)      VALUES ('$get_status_id', '$get_message', '$get_source', '$get_timestamp', '$get_uid')",     $conn);        
    }  
}             
$i = $i + 1;

if ($i<=$get_count){
echo "$i";
echo "<script>var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){\$('#import').show('fast').load('fb_import_statuses.php?i=$i').show('fast');}, 1000);    </script>";
}

else {    
    echo "Import complete:  ";
    echo "<img src='/images/check.png'>";

    }
```

Comment: OK well, some of my question didn't go because I used code.  But the code is being called inside of a DIV in my index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you add multiple `setInterval` functions (everytime the page is loaded you `echo` another method). try putting your refreshing method out of the `div` or make it call a function that includes `php` code responsible for retrieving information from db.

if you don't have to refresh the page every second, you could get all the data from db with one `php` file and return it in some form (`json` for example). I think this would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks maialithar.  I'm importing all my friends from FB using FQL and when I import more than one friend at a time the FQL times out.  So I have to do it this way to import one at a time while cycling through all my friends one after the other.

Comment: this would be sort of "brute force" and not the best solution, but you could set interval time to high value to make sure that the function will be executed only once.

Comment: Looks like I got it by adding clearInterval(auto_refresh); before var auto_refresh.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)